# app java server-client, how many client connected?

Tags: java, communication, client-server

Is it possible to know how many clients there are connected on a server? is there a method that does that, maybe in net class? or must I do a counter?

thanks

Comment: What do you use for client-server communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like `ServerSocket` has a built-in of returning a count. But because you have to manually accept connections by calling `accept()`, you can easily increment a counter. The only difficulty (if it is one) is to decrement the counter on disconnect.